# Zookeeper is not running

Tags: apache-kafka, apache-zookeeper

I am running zookeeper using command: systemctl start zookeeper. And when i check it using systemctl status zookeeper. I can see the status is Active(running) but has a : Process: 23610 ExecStop=/root/etis/kafka_2.11-1.1.0/bin/zookeeper-server-stop.sh (code=exited, status=1/FAILURE) below it. I check it with journalctl -u zookeeper command and below error shows:

```
systemd[1]: zookeeper.service: control process exited, code=exited status=1
 zookeeper-server-stop.sh[12252]: No zookeeper server to stop
 systemd[1]: Unit zookeeper.service entered failed state.
 systemd[1]: zookeeper.service failed.
 systemd[1]: zookeeper.service holdoff time over, scheduling restart.
 systemd[1]: Started Apache Zookeeper server (Kafka).
 systemd[1]: Starting Apache Zookeeper server (Kafka)...    
8-11-05 08:26:54,725] INFO Reading configuration from: /root/etis/kafka_2.11-1.1.0/config/zookeeper.properties (org.apache.zookeeper.server.quorum.QuorumPeerConfig)
    8-11-05 08:26:54,727] INFO autopurge.snapRetainCount set to 3 (org.apache.zookeeper.server.DatadirCleanupManager)
    8-11-05 08:26:54,727] INFO autopurge.purgeInterval set to 0 (org.apache.zookeeper.server.DatadirCleanupManager)
    8-11-05 08:26:54,727] INFO Purge task is not scheduled. (org.apache.zookeeper.server.DatadirCleanupManager)
    8-11-05 08:26:54,727] WARN Either no config or no quorum defined in config, running  in standalone mode (org.apache.zookeeper.server.quorum.QuorumPeerMain)
    8-11-05 08:26:54,740] INFO Reading configuration from: /root/etis/kafka_2.11-1.1.0/config/zookeeper.properties (org.apache.zookeeper.server.quorum.QuorumPeerConfig)
    8-11-05 08:26:54,740] INFO Starting server (org.apache.zookeeper.server.ZooKeeperServerMain)
    8-11-05 08:26:54,746] INFO Server environment:zookeeper.version=3.4.10-39d3a4f269333c922ed3db283be479f9deacaa0f, built on 03/23/2017 10:13 GMT (org.apache.zookeeper.server.ZooKe
    8-11-05 08:26:54,746] INFO Server environment:host.name=corp-msc-vm54 (org.apache.zookeeper.server.ZooKeeperServer)
    8-11-05 08:26:54,746] INFO Server environment:java.version=1.8.0_171 (org.apache.zookeeper.server.ZooKeeperServer)
    8-11-05 08:26:54,746] INFO Server environment:java.vendor=Oracle Corporation (org.apache.zookeeper.server.ZooKeeperServer)
    8-11-05 08:26:54,746] INFO Server environment:java.home=/usr/lib/jvm/java-1.8.0-openjdk-1.8.0.171-8.b10.el7_5.x86_64/jre (org.apache.zookeeper.server.ZooKeeperServer)
    8-11-05 08:26:54,746] INFO Server environment:java.class.path=/root/etis/kafka_2.11-1.1.0/bin/../libs/aopalliance-repackaged-2.5.0-b32.jar:/root/etis/kafka_2.11-1.1.0/bin/../lib
    8-11-05 08:26:54,747] INFO Server environment:java.library.path=/usr/java/packages/lib/amd64:/usr/lib64:/lib64:/lib:/usr/lib (org.apache.zookeeper.server.ZooKeeperServer)
    8-11-05 08:26:54,747] INFO Server environment:java.io.tmpdir=/tmp (org.apache.zookeeper.server.ZooKeeperServer)
    8-11-05 08:26:54,747] INFO Server environment:java.compiler=<NA> (org.apache.zookeeper.server.ZooKeeperServer)
    8-11-05 08:26:54,747] INFO Server environment:os.name=Linux (org.apache.zookeeper.server.ZooKeeperServer)
    8-11-05 08:26:54,747] INFO Server environment:os.arch=amd64 (org.apache.zookeeper.server.ZooKeeperServer)
    8-11-05 08:26:54,747] INFO Server environment:os.version=3.10.0-862.3.2.el7.x86_64 (org.apache.zookeeper.server.ZooKeeperServer)
    8-11-05 08:26:54,747] INFO Server environment:user.name=root (org.apache.zookeeper.server.ZooKeeperServer)
    8-11-05 08:26:54,747] INFO Server environment:user.home=/root (org.apache.zookeeper.server.ZooKeeperServer)
    8-11-05 08:26:54,747] INFO Server environment:user.dir=/root/etis/kafka_2.11-1.1.0 (org.apache.zookeeper.server.ZooKeeperServer)
    8-11-05 08:26:54,752] INFO tickTime set to 2000 (org.apache.zookeeper.server.ZooKeeperServer)
    8-11-05 08:26:54,752] INFO minSessionTimeout set to -1 (org.apache.zookeeper.server.ZooKeeperServer)
    8-11-05 08:26:54,752] INFO maxSessionTimeout set to -1 (org.apache.zookeeper.server.ZooKeeperServer)
    8-11-05 08:26:54,761] INFO binding to port 0.0.0.0/0.0.0.0:2181 (org.apache.zookeeper.server.NIOServerCnxnFactory)
    8-11-05 08:26:54,778] INFO Reading snapshot /tmp/zookeeper/version-2/snapshot.256af7 (org.apache.zookeeper.server.persistence.FileSnap)
    8-11-05 08:26:55,065] INFO Accepted socket connection from /220.5.13.121:59598 (org.apache.zookeeper.server.NIOServerCnxnFactory)
    8-11-05 08:26:55,072] WARN Exception causing close of session 0x0 due to java.io.IOException: ZooKeeperServer not running (org.apache.zookeeper.server.NIOServerCnxn)
    8-11-05 08:26:55,072] INFO Closed socket connection for client /220.5.13.121:59598 (no session established for client) (org.apache.zookeeper.server.NIOServerCnxn)
    8-11-05 08:26:55,420] ERROR Last transaction was partial. (org.apache.zookeeper.server.persistence.Util)
    8-11-05 08:26:55,421] ERROR Unexpected exception, exiting abnormally (org.apache.zookeeper.server.ZooKeeperServerMain)
    .io.EOFException
    ava.io.DataInputStream.readInt(DataInputStream.java:392)
    rg.apache.jute.BinaryInputArchive.readInt(BinaryInputArchive.java:63)
    rg.apache.zookeeper.server.persistence.FileHeader.deserialize(FileHeader.java:64)
    rg.apache.zookeeper.server.persistence.FileTxnLog$FileTxnIterator.inStreamCreated(FileTxnLog.java:585)
    rg.apache.zookeeper.server.persistence.FileTxnLog$FileTxnIterator.createInputArchive(FileTxnLog.java:604)
    rg.apache.zookeeper.server.persistence.FileTxnLog$FileTxnIterator.goToNextLog(FileTxnLog.java:570)
    rg.apache.zookeeper.server.persistence.FileTxnLog$FileTxnIterator.next(FileTxnLog.java:652)
    rg.apache.zookeeper.server.persistence.FileTxnSnapLog.restore(FileTxnSnapLog.java:166)
    rg.apache.zookeeper.server.ZKDatabase.loadDataBase(ZKDatabase.java:223)
    rg.apache.zookeeper.server.ZooKeeperServer.loadData(ZooKeeperServer.java:283)
```

What does it mean. Please help. Thanks.

Comment: Can you run Zookeeper directly using the command? for example : `/root/etis/kafka_2.11-1.1.0/bin/zookeeper-server-start.sh /root/etis/kafka_2.11-1.1.0/config/zookeeper.properties`

Comment: okay i fixed this issue by deleting the zookeeper log files. The server crashed because of the holiday shutdown.